# php bootstrapping file vs config file

Tags: php, config, bootstrapping

This might be a stupid question!

What is the difference between a bootstrap file (php bootstrapping) and config file.

Can anybody please explain the different of any?

Also could you please recommend some links on how these should be implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapping is when you create any objects required by your application to run correctly. For example, an object to manage database connections and queries. A config file is used to store information that the application requires to bootstrap. For example, the database connection details like url, username, password etc.